# Setting a ForeignKey to the current logged in user | Django Rest framework ViewSets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am building a REST API with Django Rest Framework's ViewSets and have come across a problem. When using a `POST` request on my API, I can't easily insert the current logged in user into the model.

The model I am serializing is as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    op = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = models.TextField()
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The field that is giving me the issue is the `op` field, which is a ForeignKey for Django's default `User` class.

This API has a `POST` URL for creating a new question on the site. I want the viewset to insert the *current* logged in user into the creation. Other questions have suggested defining a custom `create()` method on the serializer, but that doesn't work since I want to insert the current logged in user, and not a set one.

My Serializer:

```py
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ("op", "title", "body")
```

My viewset:

```py
class QuestionViewSet(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet,
):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your serializer to use the request user:

```
class QuestionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    op = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ("op", "title", "body")
```